# iPhone camera loses auto-focus when using ZBarSDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, autofocus, zbar-sdk

I'm working on an app that the user can select if he wants to scan a barcode or take a picture of something.
For taking a picture I'm using the `UIImagePickerController` as usual.
For scanning barcode I'm using the ZbarSDK 1.2 `ZBarReaderViewController`.

When taking a picture everything works perfect.
When scanning a barcode:
If you start the app and scan a barcode **before** taking a picture, it's also works perfect.

But is you take a picture, and then go back and try to scan a barcode, the camera loses the auto-focus and it's just impossible to scan a barcode.

To summarize:
Start -> Scan -> **Auto focus working**
Start -> Take Photo -> Back -> Scan -> **Auto focus not working**

This is how I initialize the barcode scanner:

```
-(ZBarReaderViewController *) barcodeScanner
{
    if (nil == _barcodeScanner)
    {
        _barcodeScanner = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
        _barcodeScanner.readerDelegate = self;
        _barcodeScanner.cameraMode = ZBarReaderControllerCameraModeSampling;
        _barcodeScanner.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    }
    return _barcodeScanner;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before loading up ZBarReaderViewController make sure you release UIImagePickerController, and before you load up UIImagePickerController make sure you release ZBarReaderViewController.

It took me days to figure out why i kept losing the ability to focus, and turns out that i wasn't releasing things.  For others stumbling onto this answer... You can only have 1 AVCaptureSession at a time otherwise things get screwy and you lose the ability to focus.  ZBarReaderViewController uses AVCaptureSession so make sure you release it before you initialize a new AVCaptureSession.

Comment: I'll try that... I already came to peace with the fact that I won't get an answer for this one...

Answer (score 1):

We were facing same issue with Zbar, we solved it by putting a 2 sec delay before dismissing model view.

Answer (score 0):

I would look deeper into your implementation of taking picture. Try to check if you close the resource correctly when done taking the photo. I don't think zBar implementation got anything to do with it...

Comment: The point is - I have no implementation of "Taking picture"... I'm just initializing the UIImagePickerController, present it modally and get the callback when the picture was taken. I'm not doing any fancy stuff myself.