# Releasing UIImagePickerController when using ARC

Tags: ios5, automatic-ref-counting, presentmodalviewcontroller, zbar-sdk

I am having problems whereas I lose autofocus for ZBarReaderViewController exactly like is asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658383/iphone-camera-loses-auto-focus-when-using-zbarsdk).  The apparent solution is to release the UIImagePickerController after use.  However, I am using ARC and cannot figure out how to release it.  I have tried...

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    self.imagePicker=nil;

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

however this does not appear to work.  imagePicker is an instance of UIImagePickerController.

I will mention that this may be a symptom of a bigger problem.  I am presenting the modal view from a customized tab bar that is pushed on a navigation controller from a selected table view cell.

Navigation controller>table view>accessory button on cell>push custom tab bar controller.

In order to present the modal view over both the bottom tab bar and the top navigation bar, I am presenting from the navigation controller like...

```
    BIDAppDelegate *appDelegate=(BIDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [appDelegate.navController presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

I think this is causing problems when I receive memory warnings, but I was going to try and address the ZBar autofocus issue first and see if that addresses any other problems.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Not really sure whats the layout of your app BUT to release it simply make sure nothing points to it. But still, the problem with the auto focus is in the AVCaptureSession, just restart the capture session.